# Book about a defense space station that gets a virus and some people go up to restart it

Tags: story-identification

Basic Plot:

- Tensions are high between two (possibly Middle-Eastern, or just 1 in tension with the U.S.) countries
- A U.S. Defense satellite/space station is capable of grounding/destroying missiles (like a Geneva convention-style satellite)
- Virus gets onto satellite/space station, making it allow the enemy forces to use their missiles, but not the U.S. ones
- Crew goes up to the satellite to hard-boot the system
- Space station has defenses, they must get past them all to run the hard-boot
- They eventually succeed (some of the crew may have died trying)

Comment: This was largely the plot of [Space Cowboys](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0186566/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had asked in multiple places, turns out the answer is [Virus, by Bill Buchanan](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwjN4fnfsfXHAhWCNT4KHdSoBbo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FVirus-Bill-Buchanan%2Fdp%2F0515120111&usg=AFQjCNFeEmO32QsLLTLIzPpY3jh2jzeXpQ&sig2=rn9u4PEncft9n5ShoAF5mg&bvm=bv.102537793,d.cWw)

Per a brief blurb in an [online bio of the author](http://www.mswritersandmusicians.com/mississippi-writers/bill-buchanan):

> **Virus** by Bill Buchanan is about a super virus that is uploaded into a space station that controls DEWSATs (Directed Energy Weapon
>   SATellites). Each DEWSAT was an orbiting counterstealth weapon system,
>   a satellite that could detect and destroy stealth missiles and
>   aircraft from low earth orbit...

Comment: Please add some details to your answer. Show *why* you believe this is the book the OP is looking for, preferably with quotes backing up the points in the original question.

Comment: You can click on the check mark next to your answer to accept it as the correct answer. Also, like @JoeL. says, could you please expand your answer to explain why it is the answer to your question? Finally, welcome to the SF and Fantasy Stack Exchange. Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. And enjoy your stay.